# how to display large imshow window with scrollbar (OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, crop

I have been trying several ways to display a very large image with a scrollbar, but I can't
I need to display those scrollbar because if I resize the image to fit to my window, the image is so blurry and I cant crop the image.

I tried cropping the image with the selectROI function as shown bellow:

```
im = cv2.imread(object1.toPlainText())
roi = cv2.selectROI(im)
```

Then I found a way to crop the image using nameWindow and drawing a rectangle, but I have the same  issue, I cant show scrollbars.

```
cv2.namedWindow("image",cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
```

Can you help me please?, or give me more ideas.
I tried to search in forums and the documentation but I dont have any clue :(

Thanks

Comment: OpenCV doesn't do that. you'll either have to implement some "minimap+viewport" with opencv's setmousecallback, or use an actual GUI toolkit. OpenCV is not a GUI toolkit. -- or find a build of OpenCV that comes with Qt. then the imshow window has some extra features.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristophRackwitz.
I will follow your advice and if I am able to create something, I will post it.

Comment: You  can select the roi with resized window but in back end you use the coordinates for the first image(before resize).